# Execute Perl script from Perl CGI script

Tags: perl, cgi

I want to execute a Perl script from an Apache Perl CGI script.

The CGI works perfectly showing the HTML text, but when I try to execute another script with `qx//` it doesn't work.

#### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>SUMAR</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h1>Registro de usuario</h1>
<form method="get" action="cgi-bin/index.cgi">
    Nombre <input type="text" name="name">
    <br>
    <br>
    Usuario <input type="text" name="user">
    <br>
    <br>
    Contraseña  <input type="text" name="pass">
    <br>
    <br>
    Correo electronico  <input type="text" name="email">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Perl CGI

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Unix::Passwd::File;
use File::Path;
use CGI;
use strict;

my $cgi = new CGI;
my $name = $cgi->param("name");
my $user = $cgi->param("user");
my $pass = $cgi->param("pass");
my $email = $cgi->param("email");

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<html>\n<body>\n";
print $name . $user . $pass . $email;
print "\n</body>\n</html>";

qx(perl index.pl);
```

When I execute the CGI from the command line, the call to `index.pl` works perfectly, but when I try by web it doesn't work.

EDIT:::::::::::::::.

```
apache2/error.log
.....
[Mon May 07 12:31:41.070830 2018] [cgid:error] [pid 6039:tid 139761641543424] [client 172.28.200.230:59210] End of script output before headers: index.cgi, referer: http://172.20.3.107/
[Mon May 07 12:50:14.129598 2018] [cgid:error] [pid 6523:tid 139761926846336] (13)Permission denied: AH01241: exec of '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.pl' failed
[Mon May 07 12:50:14.130080 2018] [cgid:error] [pid 6040:tid 139761717077760] [client 172.28.200.230:59324] End of script output before headers: index.pl, referer: http://172.20.3.107/
mkdir /home/hgjhh: Permission denied at index.pl line 23.
mkdir /home/hgjhh: Permission denied at index.pl line 23.
[Mon May 07 13:15:25.420469 2018] [cgid:error] [pid 6040:tid 139761599579904] [client 172.28.200.230:59613] AH01264: script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.pli
mkdir /home/hgjhh: Permission denied at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.pl line 23.
mkdir /home/hgjhh: Permission denied at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.pl line 23.
[Mon May 07 13:26:56.046889 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 6035:tid 139761926846336] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon May 07 18:22:57.342819 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 534:tid 140120374777728] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon May 07 18:22:57.364426 2018] [core:notice] [pid 534:tid 140120374777728] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making assumptions about the current work directory that may not be correct.

If `index.pl` is in the same dir as the CGI script,

```
qx(perl index.pl);
```

should be

```
use FindBin            qw( $RealBin );
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $cmd = shell_quote("perl", "--", "$RealBin/index.pl");
qx($cmd);
```

or

```
use FindBin             qw( $RealBin );
use IPC::System::Simple qw( capturex );

capturex("perl", "--", "$RealBin/index.pl");
```

In both cases, `"perl", "--", "$RealBin/index.pl"` can be reduced to `"$RealBin/index.pl"` if `index.pl` is executable.

---

This may or may not be your only problem. Until you tell us what problem you are having (e.g. by telling us what error you get), we can't help further.

Answer (score -3):

You can use system in this way:

```
system("/path/to/index.pl", @args);
```

Comment: Why will that work when `qx(perl index.pl)` does not?